# How to use sscanf where delimiter is stored in variable

Tags: c, scanf, delimiter

I have a C program that gets the input file delimiter as an argument from the user and stores it in a `char`. I then need to `sscanf` the input file based on that delimiter that the user has specified.
Is this possible?

Pseudo code:

```
char delim = getchar( );
....

// Read input file
while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in_fp)){
    sscanf(buf, "%d[delim]%c[delim]%s", &id, &sex, &dob);
}
```

Comment: You need to use `sprintf` family to create the final format string, then use it with `sscanf`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  This sounds like kind of a strange constraint.  Is this a programming assignment where you've been told which library functions you may and may not use?  Normally, the way to break a line up into fields, based on a programmable delimiter, would involve `strtok`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`sprintf`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to create the format string for [**`sscanf`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (`my_fmt_string`):

```
char my_fmt_string[32];
sprintf(my_fmt_string, "%%d%c%%c%c%%s", delim, delim);
```

*Note that we use `%%` in places where we need the format string to contain the `%` character itself for `sscanf`.*

Then use `my_fmt_string` instead of the string literal:

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in_fp)) 
{
    /*----------vvvvvvvvvvvvv-----------------*/
    sscanf(buf, my_fmt_string, &id, &sex, &dob);
}
```

**A Final Note:**
My answer above is marely attempting to answer the narrow question of dynamic formating.
But in order to use `sscanf` properly, you have to verify it succeeded by inspecting the return value. It should be the number of fields parsed (3 in this case):

```
if (sscanf(buf, my_fmt_string, &id, &sex, &dob) != 3) { /* handle error */ }
```